# While loop in a while loop PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to make a table where it changes row after 5 columns. continues to 50. Now $i <= 4 for the row.
example:

```
1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 
6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|
```

```
<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <?php
      $i = 0;
      $x = 0;
      do {
        echo "<tr>";
        $i++;
        echo "<td> " . $i . "</td";
      }
      while ( $i <= 4 );
      /* New Row */
      echo "</td></tr>";
      /* CONTINUE HERE */
      ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a loop that goes to 50, and check whether the index is a multiple of 5 with `if ($i % 5 == 0)` to start a new row.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_items; $i++) {
    if ($i % 5 == 0) { // start a row every 5 items
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . ($i + 1) . "</td>";
    if ($i % 5 == 4) { // end a row 4 items later
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
if ($i % 5 != 4) { // end the last row if there weren't a multiple of 5 items
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to insert [tr] when the $i displayed 5 times.

```
<table width="300" border="1">
<tbody>
  
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i <=50)
{
if (($i-1) %5==0)
{echo "<tr>";}
    
echo "<td>". $i . "</td>";  

$i++;
}   
?>  

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. variable i % 5 == 0 will start a new row.

```
<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <?php
      $i = 0;
      $x = 50;
      do {
        $i++;
        echo "<td> " . $i . "</td>";
        if($i % 5 == 0)
        {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
      }
      while ( $i < $x );
    ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```